# Invoking route 53 domain name changes the url in address bar to elb url

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I have a route53 url which is configured at cloudfront to redirect (http to https) to elastic load balancer url. when i invoke the route53 url , the route 53 url gets replaced with the elb url in address bar. how do prevent that?

route 53 url:  test.example.com

redirected url as per chrome : awseb-AWSEB-XXXXXXXXX-11111111.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com:443

I want browser to retain the same url in the address bar.

~Ann

Comment: What are the exact settings of your R53, CF and ALB listener rules?

Comment: Are you using a `CNAME` or `ALIAS` DNS resource record? Hint: you should be using `ALIAS` resource records.